# Rotating Text -90 in QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, angles

[image]I have rotated some text labels by -90 in my project.  I want them to stand vertically on an alignment bar.  If the map window with the alignment bar also has a rotation the text is no longer vertical or horizontal.  I am not sure where this text angle is coming from.  (Please see picture.)  The "3+200.00" is set horizontal and transposes between map windows correctly.  The "Dugout 4" is set to -90 and acquires an off-angle somewhere when it transposes to the map window.  Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this?

[image: Text with odd angle]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of the settings of the "dugout 4" label, thank you.

Comment: Not sure what setting I can show you.

Comment: Sorry cant seem to add an image.

Comment: Image added to top.

Comment: Please add the label settings, not the "expression" you use for the rotation.

Comment: Sorry Erik.  I'm confused.  There are literally a hundred settings in eight different panels with respect to labels.  What is it you want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the expression ((-90) - @map_rotation) to account for the rotation applied to the Map canvas.

[image]   [image]

Note: the Expression Builder's *Variables* dropdown is a great place to look for other dynamic variables.

[image]

Comment: Mikeoramma Everything looks good on my end, glad it worked out.