# Keep labels upright when QGIS map rotated in layout relative to canvas

Tags: qgis, labeling, rotate

I have the following in my canvas:

[image]

I have rotated it to fit in my layout:

[image]

I have attempted several methods, e.g. [Is there a way to interactively rotate labels in QGIS using any of the edit tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232727), [Rotating Text -90 in QGIS Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346725) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232727/is-there-a-way-to-interactively-rotate-labels-in-qgis-using-any-of-the-edit-tool).

I'm using QGIS 3.18.3-Zürich

Comment: How are your label position defined ? do you set a label rotation ? the default for label is to stay horizontal regardless of canvas rotation

Answer (score 1):

Atleast with simple labels, you can go to the layer properties > labels > formatting > text orientation and select "Rotation-based".
[image]

It appears you can do this too in formatting when creating a rule in rule-based labeling.